# Laravel website sometimes connecting to old database

Tags: php, laravel

I have UAT and Production websites.
My UAT website sometimes connecting to main database although I changed the database connection in `.env` file.
After changing connection, I also run the following Artisan commands:

`php artisan cache:clear`

`php artisan config:clear`

`php artisan config:cache`

But it is not working.

Here is my `.env` file.

```
APP_NAME=my_app_name
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=db_uat
DB_USERNAME=
DB_PASSWORD=

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
```

Here is my `config\database.php` file.

```
'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),

    'connections' => [
        'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', ''),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'db_uat'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', ''),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => false,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],
    ],
```

Comment: Welcome to SO ...  can you check your `config/database.php` default value ?

Comment: is `db_uat` this your old database name?

Comment: ```db_uat```  is new database name

Comment: then all goods here you need to debug that

Comment: Welcome on board Krystal
I'd like to know what do you mean by "sometimes connecting to main database" do you mean than the site, within the same browsing session gets the data from 2 different databases? I.e one request is served from uat db and the other is served from prod db? Kindly elaborate.

Comment: @HasnaaIbraheem Yes, in same browsing session, getting data from two databases. E.g When I load a page, It serve data from uat_db (the right db), and then I click a button (that btn get data by ajax call), then it gets data from prod db.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote php once in my life so the comment will not mainly to answer your question rather than how to debug the issue
First try to switch off the non-prod db server until you finish your debugging. Then restart your prod application server (if possible). You may also try to "Empty cache and hard reload from browser"
In the backend page that is called by the ajax (that uses wrong db) try to print to a log file the database variables used (DB_URL for instance), check if it consistently accesses the wrong database, if so, could be that your database settings is overwritten somewhere in your application.
Kindly check that and keep us posted.